# Next.js url structure for multi language sites

Tags: next.js

I'm migrating my app to Next.js. Currently I have a url structure like this:

```
www.example.com/ <-- English
www.example.com/de <-- German
www.example.com/page <-- English
www.example.com/de/page <-- German
```

So my english website does not have the language in the url. If someone tries to access the website with "en" in the url he will be forwarded.

How would I achieve this in Next.js? Having always two files (i.e. "[language].js" and "index.js") in the /pages directory seems to be not the right solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Some help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Next.js 9.4 there is an experimental feature "Custom Routes". This provides a more elegent solution. See the discussion here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9081

Example usage:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      // Basic `path-to-regexp` usage
      // Query object shape: { id: string }
      { source: "/user/:id", destination: "/user_profile" },

      // Optional Language
      // Query object shape: { lang?: string }
      { source: "/:lang(en|es)?/about", destination: "/about" },

      // Advanced rewrite
      // Query object shape: { id: string } (in addition to dynamic route param)
      { source: "/u/:id", destination: "/user/:id" }
    ];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

With NextJS 10 you can do this [natively](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing).
Your next.config.js would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

The `defaultLocale` is the language for [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/).

Then you can use a library like [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) to store the translations.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: As [nunorbatista said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176039/7218900):  With NextJS 10 you can do this natively. Your next.config.js would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

Old answer:

The folder structure is correct, but you don’t need to write duplicate code inside `[language]` folder. Just import the page from ”main” folder. Multilingual is currenly a bit complex to setup with Next.js. Here is the situation at the moment.

If you want to use library

- with serverless deployment you should watch this one.

  - https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate
- without serverless deployment you should watch this one.

  - https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

If you want to do it on your own, you should modify them to match your needs.

- Next.js version 9.3 or above

  - https://codesandbox.io/s/92ebn
- Next.js version below 9.3

  - https://github.com/fwojciec/simple-i18n-example

Comment: Thanks. I do it like this now:
`import IndexPage, { getStaticProps, getStaticPaths } from '@/pages/index';
export { getStaticProps, getStaticPaths } ;
export default IndexPage;`